# Facebook graph api : how to filter app feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the graph api to display all the feed of an app. 
Here is my simple code :

```
$url = $facebook->api('/' . $_REQUEST["app"] . '/feed?date_format=U&limit=10');
$feed = $url[data];
<pre><?php print_r($feed); ?></pre>
```

As you can see, it's very easy.

The pb : i want only the feed from the app and not from all the users who post comments. Apparently, that's depend of the configuration of the app, but i wonder if it exists a filter on the [from] parameter ?

Thks
Vince

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use FQL Query on the /fql endpoint.

You'll use a query on the `stream` table and a subquery on the `stream_filter` table. Documentation on [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) and [stream_filter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter)

Comment: I don't that method, i will have a look.

No way to filter it through the API ?

Comment: No. Use must use FQL for this. You just use the /fql endpoint and put the query in the "q" parameter. Quite easy.